# Python package names collision

Tags: python, package, name-collision

I have a following project structure:

```
program_name/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    package_name/
        __init__.py
        some_module.py
```

when I run `python program_name` from top level directory I get an error. It appears, that some of mine dependencies import the package with the same name as mine. Namely I import `numpy` in `__main__.py` and, somewhere deep inside, it has `import package_name` line. So instead of importing its dependency it import my package.

Can I solve it, without renaming my package? I can understand name collision with third party packages you use directly in your project. But here I have a name collision with some of the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect `sys.path`, you can know the search order used by your application.

You can modify the order befor import the incriminated library and after make an explicit import to reach your library.

In my opinion it is better change your package name.

Comment: Seems like so. Just cannot figure out a proper new name. It was `ast` - simple and clear. Seems like now I have to call it `ast_framework` or something like that. It became long and `_framework` suffix is meaningless(